# Python - list of lists - check if unique combination of values has last different value in the list

Tags: python, python-3.8

we have a list of lists

```
links_list = [['project1','repo1', 'folder1', 'target1', 'link1', 'branch1'], 
             ['project1', 'repo1', 'folder1', 'target1', 'link1', 'branch1'], 
             ['project1', 'repo1', 'folder1', 'target1', 'link1', 'branch2'],
             ['project2', 'repo2', 'folder2', 'target2', 'link2', 'branch2']]

for link_list in links_list:
    print(link_list)
```

Our unique combination of columns are: **project, repo, folder** and **target**

That means, it is OK if we have lists which are repeated such as the first two lists:

```
['project1', 'repo1', 'folder1', 'target1', 'link1', 'branch1'], 
['project1', 'repo1', 'folder1', 'target1', 'link1', 'branch1']
```

That is not an issue.

it is NOT OK if **BRANCH** column (the last column) is different for this combination of the first 4 columns: **project, repo, folder** and **target**.

So since we have

`['project1', 'repo1', 'folder1', 'target1', 'link1', 'branch1']` and

`['project1', 'repo1', 'folder1', 'target1', 'link1', 'branch2']`
we do not know which **BRANCH** value is valid so script should exit and throw exception for this use case because for combination:
**'project1', 'repo1', 'folder1', 'target1'** we have two branches: **branch1** and **branch2** which makes inconsistency.

**Link** column (column5 - index4) is irrelevant for the logic.

I am really not sure how to start here.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
combos = {}
for link_list in links_list:
  key = tuple(link_list[:4])
  branch = link_list[5]
  if combos.setdefault(key, branch) != branch:
    raise Exception(f"{key} already has branch '{combos[key]}'.")
```

You can use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to set and/or retrieve the existing key.

Answer (score 1):

make the first four column value as a key, the branch columns as value.

```
links_dict = {}
for link_list in links_list:
    key = tuple(link_list[0:4])
    value = link_list[5]
    if key not in links_dict:
        links_dict[key] = value
        continue
    else:
        if links_dict[key] != value:
            raise Exception(link_list)
```

Comment: "value" must be the tuple as well? or its ok to have it as regular string value?